# ArrayCollection error in Flex does not accept single XML nodes - alternatives?

Tags: apache-flex, arrays, arraycollection

i get this error when i retrieve an XML that only has 1 node (no repeating nodes) and i try to store in an ArrayCollection. -When I have MORE than 1 "name" nodes...i do NOT get an error.

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "XXXXXX" to mx.collections.ArrayCollection.
```

this error occurs as the line of code:

```
myList= e.result.list.name;
```

Why can't ArrayCollection work with a single node? I'm using this ArrayCollection as a dataprovider for a Component -is there an alternative I can use that will take BOTH single and repeating nodes as well as work as a dataprovider?  Thanks in advance!

code:

```
[Bindable]
private var myList:ArrayCollection= new ArrayCollection();

        private function getList(e:Event):void{

            var getStudyLoungesService:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
            getStuffService.url = "website.com/asdf.php";
            getStuffService.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, onGetList);
            getStuffService.send();

        }

        private function onGetList(e:ResultEvent):void{

            myList= e.result.list.name;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `resultFormat` should be set to `e4x`:

```
var getStudyLoungesService:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
getStuffService.url = "website.com/asdf.php";
getStuffService.resultFormat = "e4x";
getStuffService.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, onGetList);
getStuffService.send();
```

You can then retrieve the results as follows:

```
new XMLListCollection(e.result.list.name);
```

(All credits to Amarghosh, been banging my head on that one for hours, but nearly missed his comment!)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly assign an `XML` or even an `XMLList` to a variable of type `ArrayCollection`. Use an `XMLListCollection` and pass the data to its constructor.

```
[Bindable]
private var myList:XMLListCollection;

myList = new XMLListCollection(e.result.list.name);
```

Comment: thanks Amarghosh.  However, it doesn't look like XMLList is a valid dataprovider.. I'm getting this error:

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert mx.collections::ArrayCollection@ddbc7c1 to XMLList.

Is there another data type that I can still use?

Comment: it's not XMLList, it's `XMLListCollection`. Change the type of myList from array collection to xmllist collection

Comment: hi again amarghosh, i have tried XMLListCollection, however recieved this error:

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert mx.collections::ArrayCollection@aaa0301 to XMLList.

i am sure when it is of type XMLList because 

private var studyLounges:XMLListCollection;

is my initialization.  any other thoughts what alternative data types?

Comment: Are you sure you're receiving XML in your result?

Comment: @Rees In your HTTPService, set the attribute `resultFormat="e4x"`. Thanks @Mike for triggering it :)